# Iterating over different objects descended from same base class

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have various classes which define the structural elements of a piece of music. The hierarchy is `Song` > `Section` > `CompositeMusic` > `MusicTime`, all of which inherit from an abstract `MusicComponent` class.

`MusicTime` is the bottom level and knows which `Chord` to play and for how many crotchets, and are contained in bars in `CompositeMusic` objects. `Section` in turn holds the `CompositeMusics` and is there to allow for tempo and time signature changes.

I need to be able to recursively iterate through all `Sections` in the `Song`, all `CompositeMusics` in each `Section`, and play all `MusicTimes` in each `CompositeMusic`. In other words, iterate through all the children in each type unless it's a `MusicTime` in which case play it.

I naively thought I would be able to put an abstract `List<MusicComponent> getChildren()` on the `MusicComponent` base class so I could iterate over any descendant in the same way. However this isn't allowed as it won't accept a `List<Section>` for example.

So my question is, what is the correct method to recursively iterate over different objects descended from the same base class?

**EDIT**

Code samples, as requested:

*Base class*

```
public abstract class MusicComponent {

    public MusicComponent() {

    }

    public abstract void play();
    public abstract boolean addComponent(MusicComponent component);
    public abstract List<MusicComponent> getChildren();

}
```

*Example of sub class*

```
public class Song extends MusicComponent {

    String songName;
    List<Section> sections;

    public Song(String songName, List<Section> sections) {

        this.songName = songName;
        this.sections = sections;
    }
```

This is what I want to do on `Song` (and equivalent for `Section` and `CompositeMusic`)

```
@Override
public List<MusicComponent> getChildren() {
    return sections;
}
```

But it throws an compile error as it can't implicitly convert from `List<Section>` to `List<MusicComponent>` even though `Section` is descended from `MusicComponent`, which is what I'd hoped to be able to do

Comment: Can you add some code samples to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `List<? extends MusicComponent>` as return type

Answer (score 0):

From Java 1.5 covariant return types are supported so basically the method getChildren() will be able to return any list of the subclasses of MusicComponent if the base class method is overriden. What you need to do is before you iterate check using instanceof to make sure that the list variable that you want to iterate is of the correct type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've edited my question, from what you're saying shouldn't my code work? It giving a type mismatch

Comment: Are you sure you are using Java 1.5+? Because if you do this will be just fine. Maybe you should also show that part of the code that gives the error, the iteration part. I was wondering also shouldn't you have included the Section class in the code above and shouldn't that overriding happen in Section class itself?

Answer (score 0):

Please see Visitor design pattern in Wikipedia. It is a classic way to recursively iterate complex hierarchy.
Design patterns  is overhead for simple use cases but it can help if your model will evolve in the future.